# Count records that exist within recurring 30 day period

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a need to count calls that exist within a rolling 30 day period, based on a `@StartDate` for a starting point. So for example, let's say I have a table with the phone #, datetime and RN which is the `ROW_NUMBER` function partitioned by number and ordered by date desc. Then, let's say I have `@StartDate = '1/1/2018'`.

So the beginning of this 30 day counting would begin with the first row, `2019-11-21 13:15:27.759`. Within a 30 day period, included in this calculation would be the top 3 rows. Next, row 4 through 6 would be grouped together. Then 7 through 11. If you move down to row 12, that row through row 15 would be grouped together since they are within a 30 day period. If we only look at these rows up through row 15, I would expect to see a count of 4 for this phone number.

I have attempted to use `ROW_NUMBER` in conjunction with a WHERE clause that stipulates `DATEDIFF(DAY,a.InitiatedDateTimeUTC, u.InitiatedDateTimeUTC) BETWEEN 0 and 30)`, within the context of a self join, but my numbers just aren't right. What's the best way to get this data? This is a weird request that I've gotten and I've never had to aggregate data this way before, so it has kinda stumped me.

```
create table #data (phone varchar(20), InitiatedDateTimeUTC datetime, rn tinyint)
insert into #data values
('555-555-5555',    '2019-11-21 13:15:27.759',  '1'),
('555-555-5555',    '2019-11-21 13:13:48.121',  '2'),
('555-555-5555',    '2019-11-11 19:46:38.511',  '3'),
('555-555-5555',    '2018-08-29 13:48:26.796',  '4'),
('555-555-5555',    '2018-08-10 21:42:21.037',  '5'),
('555-555-5555',    '2018-08-10 21:25:52.948',  '6'),
('555-555-5555',    '2018-04-25 19:55:04.158',  '7'),
('555-555-5555',    '2018-04-25 19:54:01.818',  '8'),
('555-555-5555',    '2018-04-25 19:49:55.074',  '9'),
('555-555-5555',    '2018-04-24 20:57:27.768',  '10'),
('555-555-5555',    '2018-04-24 20:44:42.660',  '11'),
('555-555-5555',    '2018-03-19 15:56:12.395',  '12'),
('555-555-5555',    '2018-02-23 17:49:14.203',  '13'),
('555-555-5555',    '2018-02-23 17:44:16.258',  '14'),
('555-555-5555',    '2018-02-19 17:31:34.654',  '15')
```

---

**Attempt:**

```
DROP TABLE #AllCalls     

SELECT RemoteID ,InitiatedDateTimeUTC, 
row_id = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY RemoteID 
  ORDER BY InitiatedDateTimeUTC ASC)  
INTO #AllCalls
FROM InteractionSummary 
WHERE ConnectionType = 1 and Direction = 1 
AND InitiatedDateTimeUTC > '1/1/2017' AND RemoteID IS NOT NULL    
 

SELECT a.*, DATEDIFF(DAY,a.InitiatedDateTimeUTC, u.InitiatedDateTimeUTC)
FROM #AllCalls a
LEFT JOIN #AllCalls u ON (a.RemoteID = u.RemoteID 
    AND a.row_id + 1 = u.row_id 
    AND DATEDIFF(DAY,a.InitiatedDateTimeUTC, u.InitiatedDateTimeUTC) BETWEEN 0 and 30 )
WHERE u.row_id IS NULL --Only unique 
ORDER BY 1,2
```

---

**Desired Results:**

| RemoteID | Count |
| --- | --- |
| 555-555-5555 | 4 |

Comment: Please show us said attempt. And show your desired results.

Comment: What about a bunch of days which are within 30 days of each other, but the first and last of those rows are more than 30 days?

Comment: Charlieface-I'm fairly confident that scenario doesn't exist (this data reflects people who call in, so a person would have to call in at least once a day for over a month), but that is a great question and one I considered but dismissed upon the realization described above. Thanks for checking though

Comment: Not sure I quite understood that: someone could call in only 3 times, once after 28 days, once after 35 days, total is 35 days start to finish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to count the number of gaps between phone numbers that are 30 or more days apart.  You can simply use `lag()` and conditional aggregation:

```
select d.phone,
       sum(case when prev_InitiatedDateTimeUTC > dateadd(day, -30, InitiatedDateTimeUTC) then 0 else 1 end)
from (select d.*,
             lag(InitiatedDateTimeUTC) over (partition by phone order by InitiatedDateTimeUTC) as prev_InitiatedDateTimeUTC
      from data d
     ) d
group by d.phone;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=6549ee438a97c8e6dda4f90bb24175e3) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: I totally forgot about `LAG()` and `LEAD()`. Great functions. This appears to do what I need, thank you much Gordon.

Answer (score 0):

This may or may not serve your needs, but it hits all the points you brought up as far as I can tell.

```
SELECT  t.Grouping
        ,t.phone
        ,COUNT(1) AS CallCount
FROM    (
            SELECT  DISTINCT
                    CAST(t.MonthGroup AS VARCHAR)+'-'+CAST(t.YearGroup AS VARCHAR) AS Grouping
                    ,d.phone
                    ,d.InitiatedDateTimeUTC
                    ,d.rn
            FROM    #data AS d
                    INNER JOIN (
                                   SELECT   d.InitiatedDateTimeUTC AS FirstDate
                                            ,d2.InitiatedDateTimeUTC AS LastDate
                                            ,MONTH(d.InitiatedDateTimeUTC) AS MonthGroup
                                            ,YEAR(d.InitiatedDateTimeUTC) AS YearGroup
                                            ,DATEDIFF(DAY, d.InitiatedDateTimeUTC, GETDATE()) AS Age
                                   FROM     #data AS d
                                            CROSS JOIN #data AS d2
                                   WHERE    DATEDIFF(DAY, d.InitiatedDateTimeUTC, d2.InitiatedDateTimeUTC) <= 30
                                            AND DATEDIFF(DAY, d.InitiatedDateTimeUTC, d2.InitiatedDateTimeUTC) > 0
                               ) AS t ON (
                                             d.InitiatedDateTimeUTC = t.FirstDate
                                             OR d.InitiatedDateTimeUTC = t.LastDate
                                         )
            WHERE   1 = 1
                    AND d.InitiatedDateTimeUTC > @StartDate
        ) AS t
GROUP BY t.Grouping
        ,t.phone
```

Comment: I'm attempting to run this, and even though it's all on temp tables and not drawing from DB tables, it's taking forever to run. I'm not sure that this is going to be the solution on that basis alone. EDIT: to be clear, it's taking forever when I try to run it against my entire dataset, not just the subset I provided in the question.

Comment: Makes sense. A CROSS JOIN on a large dataset could get very spendy.
It would help to establish Min and Max dates one level higher to restrict the window of the data going into the temp table.
Also, how is your tempdb configured? Do you have nine equally-sized files on a dedicated drive?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possible solution you can try.

It makes use of a numbers list / tally table - I'm generating one on the fly for this example but you would have a permanent table available.

```
with numbers as (select top(365) Row_Number() over(order by (select null)) as n from sys.messages),
dates as (select n,DateAdd(day,n,(select Min(InitiatedDateTimeUTC) from #data)) as date from numbers),
datelist as (select *, Lead(date) over(order by n) ndate from dates)
select d.phone, Count(distinct Floor(n/30.0))[Count]
from datelist dl 
join #data d on d.InitiatedDateTimeUTC>=dl.date and d.InitiatedDateTimeUTC < dl.ndate
group by d.phone
```

See [working Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=1f3c83d8508f3b633e376491b9ecc1f2)

Comment: This gets very close. For some reason, I'm getting 5 instead of 4. The preliminary data is the same, so I'm not sure why the results differ.

Comment: That's odd - I get 4 using the sample data from your post - and so does the DB Fiddle link!

Comment: I know, that's what's so strange lol I checked my temp table, #Data, and it's exactly the same. But for some reason, it's giving me 5. Regardless, I like your approach and will try to remember your technique for future scenarios.

Comment: I *suspect* your test data might not be fully representative of your requirements, based on your description to count the dates in each consecutive 30-day period offset from the earliest date, at least that's how I understood it.

Comment: It could very well be an oversight on my part, some aspect not considered. I'd have to unpack the logic, which I'm likely to do at some point because I have a need to understand things, but for the time being, I'm going to go with Gordon's answer for the sake of timeliness since I am trying to put this together for the C-suites. Thanks again my friend, I may come back and ask you questions on this.